# MS Office Webservice toolkit for Office 2007?

Tags: web-services, vba, soap

There is an article here for MS Office 2003
http://metrix.fcny.org/wiki/display/tips/How+to+Create+a+Microsoft+Access+Client+for+a+SOAP-based+Web+Service+API

When I tried to install http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fa36018a-e1cf-48a3-9b35-169d819ecf18&DisplayLang=en it says it requires Office 2003 whereas I have Office 2007 and I can't find update for Office 2007 ?

Does it exist if not how do I access a soap webservice from VBA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Web Services Toolkit used the SOAP toolkit, which is no longer supported. However, there are a couple of options available, which include:

- [XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - Relies on [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [ServerXMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762278%28VS.85%29.aspx) - Offers much of the same functionality as XMLHTTP, but does not rely on WinInet. See the [FAQ](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761) for more information.
- [Managed Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2008/01/02/soap-toolkit-vista-excel-2007-call-web-services-impossible.aspx) - Using .NET utilizing VSTO or an Excel Workbook project.

Here are a few examples.

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/#_Toc173749360

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819156%28office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168471%28office.11%29.aspx