# How to use XML web services in Access2007 which are built on Visual studio (2008/2010)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ms-access, c#-to-vb.net

I want to build some web services on Visual Studio (2008/2010) and want to add reference in Access 2007.  Any one please suggest me how can i use web services in Access2007.  I have searched on internet but i could not find any where.  If possible please help me with a template(code sample) or steps to use/call web services in Access 2007.
Do I need to use any third party tool that which supports linking or using web services please help me.

Comment: Check this existing SO(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797672/ms-office-webservice-toolkit-for-office-2007) suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most lightweight approach is to use the MSXML library.

You code thus will look like:

```
  Dim objXML           As Object
  Dim strSymbol        As String
  Dim strURL           As String
  Dim strWFormat       As String

  Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

  strURL = "http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="
  strWFormat = "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"

  strSymbol = "MSFT"

  objXML.Open "GET", strURL & strSymbol & strWFormat, False
  objXML.Send

  Debug.Print "Symbol = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(0)
  Debug.Print "Trade  = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(1)
  Debug.Print "Date   = " & Split(objXML.ResponseText, ",")(2)
```

The above hits the yahoo stock quote web service and returns csv, but teh xml object is happy with xml data.

So, this approach works well for most web services.

Comment: Alber D. Kallal,  I have tried using the above code, by using XMLHTTP object.  It did worked fantastically.   Slight correction in url, it was not fetching the values may be there is any typo error, so i just googled to get yahoo quotes. I did found the below link and it worked fine.

 strURL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="
  strWFormat = "&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv"
  strSymbol = "MSFT"  'Microsoft Corpora

Thank you once again for you great help in this regard.